# A problem regarding Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

It is a given problem of the book LINEAR ALGEBRA by  Hoffman & Kunze (page 96)

Let $V$ be an $n$- dimensional vector space over the field $F$, and let $B=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$.

(a) $\exists$ a unique linear operator $T$ on $V$ such that $T\alpha_j =\alpha_k,k=j+1,   j=1,...,n-1,  T\alpha_n =0$. What is the matrix $A$ of $T$ in the ordered basis $B$ ?

(b) Prove that $T^n=0$ but $T^m \ne 0,m=n-1$

(c) Let $S$ be any linear operator on $V$ such that $S^n=0$ but $S^m \ne 0 ,m=n-1$  .Prove that  there is an ordered basis $B^*$ for $V$ such that the matrix of $S$ in the ordered basis $B^*$ is the matrix $A$ of part (a).

my try : (a) and (b) is easy to compute. my problem is to prove part (c).
for simplicity I have assumed $n=2$. We know that the matrix with respect to  the standered ordered basis of a given linear map treats as the same linear map.So I name that matrix $B$ and $B= \{\begin {bmatrix}
                                        a&b\\
                                        c&d\\
                                      \end{bmatrix}\}$

Since $S^2=0 , S\ne 0$ the rank of $S$ is one.So I assume $c=\alpha a, d=\alpha b$. Let $X=$[1      0]$\in R^2$ then $B^2X=0$ gives $\alpha= -a/b$.

Thus we get $S(x,y)=xS(1,0)+yS(0,1)=x(a ,\alpha a)+y(b,\alpha b)=(ax+by)(1,-a/b)$. I take $B^*=$$\{\beta_1=(0,1);\beta_2=(b,-a)\}$ then $S\beta_1=\beta_2$ and $S\beta_2=0$. And hence we get the matrix of $S$ with respect to $B^*$ ,which is $\{\begin {bmatrix}
          0&0\\
          1&0\\
          \end{bmatrix}\}=A$.

So we are done, assuming $n=2$ but how to do the general case. It seems to me very difficult in $n$ dimensional case if I generalise my try.Please someone give me a hint to solve part (c).Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\{0\}\varsubsetneq\ker S\varsubsetneq\ker S^2\varsubsetneq\cdots\varsubsetneq\ker S^{n-1}\varsubsetneq\ker S^n=V$. So, take an element of $\ker S\setminus\{0\}$, then an element of $\ker S^2\setminus\ker S$ and so on.

Comment: Yes! rank of $S$ is need to be $n-1$, So dimension of Kernel of $S$ is 1,and rank of $S*S*s...*S$ (n-1 times) is 1.$KerS^i=kerS^(i+1)$ implies $S$ is injective.Using this and the fact that $KerS^i\subset KerS^(i+1)$ your claim is proved. Let $v_n\in KerS$ ,$v_(n-1)\in KerS^2\KerS^1 ,$v_(n-2)\in KerS^3\KerS^2$,... and so on.

Comment: Sorry for my typing error in coment....Those $v_i$ gives a lower trianguler matrix with all the entries as 0 in diagonal. which is similar to the matrix $A$.Your hint is most valueable indeed,sir.Thank you!